# how to obtain the service of a computer in a csv format

Tags: awk, sed, service, grep

I want to get the service of a computer using :

```
systemctl list-unit-files --no-legend -t service | awk '{ sub(/\.service$/, "", $1); print "SERVICE:" $1 "|" $2 }'
```

but it gives me the Following result :

```
SERVICE: syslog|enable
```

(for example)

and i would love to get this :

```
"SERVICE","syslog","enable",
```

I tried several syntax but it generates errors because of the `' "" '`.
i even tried to put some other `printf '","'` but it brake the `awk` sentence because of the the `'` at the beginning.

i tried to use `sed` and `grep` but it modifies the

```
systemctl list-unit-files --no-legend -t service
```

directly which breaks my script.

How can i parse the result in a CSV format ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing your efforts in form code in your question(keep it up). Kindly do post samples of `systemctl list-unit-files --no-legend -t service` command output also so that we can get more clear picture of your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting to try this solution:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --no-legend -t service| awk '{printf("\"SERVICE\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n",$1,$2)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you intend to remove `.service` from the service names, you can try this `sed`

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files --no-legend -t service | sed 's/\([^.]*\)\.[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]\+\([^[:space:]]*\)/"SERVICE","\1","\2",/'
"SERVICE","syslog","enabled",
```

`\([^.]*\)` - Match until the next occurance of a period. As it is within a parenthesis, group it to be returned at a later time with back reference `\1`

`\.[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]\+` - As this part is not within a parenthesis, it will be excluded. This will exclude from the period `.` up to the the space.

`\([^[:space:]]*\)` - Group the rest up to the next space, it is grouped and will be returned with back reference `\2`

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's perfect ! How did you do it ?

Comment: What does "/\" means at the begining ? I know that "s" means that we substract infos. is that right ?

Comment: I asume you wrote "SERVICE","syslog","enabled", at the end to show what it print and it's not an actual commande part. Im i right ?

Comment: @cyp, please check edit. The ` /\\` at the beginning is a delimiter `/` and escaping the opening of a parenthesis used for grouping ` \\`, the `s`  is for substitution. Yes, the output at the bottom will be the output after running the command.